# can't use returend result Json in any class

Tags: json, swift, swift2

i'm new to swift 2 langue and I'm try to use Json file inside my project so i go to use SwiftyJson library framework,but i got small problem that is i can't use the returned result from the son file in class of my project

this is my code

```
import UIKit

class NewsViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var championlist: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    private var imagesArray = ["About" , "About" , "About" , "About" , "Logo" , "Search" , "About"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "json") {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
                let json = JSON(data: data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
                print (json["keys"]["117"])
                let champlist = json["keys"].count
            }
        }

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

     func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(championlist: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    func collectionView(championlist: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return self.champlist.count
    }

    func collectionView(championlist: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = championlist.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.image.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.label.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        //var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        // Configure the cell

        return cell
    }

}
```

i got error (Use of unresolved identifier 'chmplist'

Comment: If you can add your json file as well , that would be better

Comment: the JSON file is fine , the problem here (Use of unresolved identifier 'chmplist')

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a variable defined inside a scope (set of braces) and then return it outside of it.
do this

```
var chmplist = 0
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "json") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
        let json = JSON(data: data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
        print (json["keys"]["117"]) // this print Moha
      chmplist = (json["keys"].count) // this print number of keys
    }
}
return chmplist
```

UPDATE: after seeing the updated code:

championlist is not the same as champlist :).

Comment: unexpected non-void return value in void function ,,

Comment: @MohammedAwad, please edit the question and post the whole function's code.

Comment: done ,, the problem is here 
return self.champlist.count
Use of unresolved identifier 'chmplist'

Comment: self.champlist.count must be self.championlist.count

Comment: same error :'( ,, unexpected non-void return value in void function

Comment: which line? i dont see a "return" call in that function

Comment: sry function collectionView and the error tell me ( value of type(NewsViewController) has no member 'chmplist'

Comment: change this line
return self.champlist.count
to
return self.championlist.count

Comment: UIviewcontroller has no member name 'count'

Comment: I sincerely hope someone is able to help u :). I can't i m sorry.